# What we should use instead of Spring Security's JSP tag library to have security in client side in HTML pages?

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-page-application

As you know in the project that the UI is `html` pages and not `jsp` (something like [jhipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) applications), we cannot using from Spring Security's JSP tag library. what is the best strategy to havnig security in client side?

for example in jsp pages i use this code to show or hide simple button based on user access:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">
<button type="button"></button>
</sec:authorize>
```

now, how can i do this in html page?

Comment: JHipster apps use Thymeleaf only for email messages not for web pages, they are single page applications built on top of angular. So your question should not be tagged with jhipster otherwise answers are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Thymeleaf` and in particular [its Spring Security integration Guide](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html).

Comment: Exactly, JHipster uses Thymeleaf, so the HTML files are actually templates, this are processed, and Thymeleaf has a security namespace.

Comment: @Klaus Groenbaek : not you mate, I had 2 upvotes and a 3rd person downvoted i can see it in my profile so was asking for explanation

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the servlet context (or spring security related state) if your view is a simple html page.

The html files in JHipster are not normal HTML files, they are Thymeleaf templates. JHipster produces a Spring boot applications, and when thymeleaf is in the classpath, it will be the default view resolver.

If you are interested in the a simple example, you can clone the following repository https://bitbucket.org/Klaus_Groenbaek/performance.git. The module "stateful" has a simple form based login, which uses thymeleaf templates and Spring security. The reference to the thymeleaf security namespace, is found in /stateful/src/main/resources/templates/navigation.html